# Jinja TemplateNotFound when try to format a string inside a template

Tags: python, jinja2, airflow

I have a jinja template that refer to an sql file which is going to be run by the Airflow operator. (According to this [Airflow doc](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/operators/cloud/bigquery.html#execute-bigquery-jobs))

```
execute_query = BigQueryInsertJobOperator(
        task_id="execute_query_task",
        configuration={
            "query": {
                "query" : "{% include 'folder/final_tableA.sql' %}",
                "useLegacySql": False,
            }
        }
    )
```

which it work perfectly. But my question here is that what if I have to dynamically change the file name or folder. This operator run inside a for loop of table list e.g. tableA, tableB, tableC . . .
How can I format the string inside this template?

This is what I tried but failed

```
table = "tableB"
execute_query = BigQueryInsertJobOperator(
          . 
          . 
          . 
"       "query" : {% include 'folder/final_{}.sql'.format(table) %}"
```

and got this error

```
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: folder/final_{'json': None, 'value': None}.sql
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not seeing a DAG doesn't help but have you tried?

```py
"query": "{{% include 'folder/final_{}.sql'%}}".format(table)
```

The `{{` is to do escaping for templating string with `format`.